# Run Ruby Script From PHP

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a PHP project in-which I need to convert a .slim (http://slim-lang.com/) file to regular HTML.

Unfortunately, it seems the only way of doing this is through using Ruby as I can't find any PHP parsers for slim.

However, I'm totally new to ruby and have never even used it before. Anyways, I'm going to have to execute a .rb file from PHP to do the conversion.

However, I'm having trouble setting up ruby to run properly (I believe).

I setup a folder (slim) with the following:

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem "listen"
gem "slim"
gem "sass"
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
   GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    ffi (1.9.0)
    listen (1.3.0)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
      rb-kqueue (>= 0.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.3)
    rb-inotify (0.9.1)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rb-kqueue (0.2.0)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    sass (3.2.10)
    slim (2.0.1)
      temple (~> 0.6.6)
      tilt (>= 1.3.3, < 2.1)
    temple (0.6.6)
    tilt (1.4.1)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  listen
  sass
  slim
```

**main.rb**

```
require 'listen'
require 'slim'


# if source folder specified
if ARGV[0]
  Listen.to!(ARGV[0], :filter => /\.slim$/) do |modified, added| 
    modified.each do |modified_file|
      system("slimrb --pretty #{modified_file} > #{modified_file.gsub('.slim','')}.html --trace")
    end
  end
end
```

So from what I understand, this should get any file with a .slim extension and convert it to .html

Then in my PHP I've got:

```
<?php 

$pathToRB = "http://example.com/path/to/ruby/file/main.rb";

exec($pathToRB);

?>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't do anything though. I'm pretty sure this has something to do with having ruby running on the server or something, but like I said, I'm totally new to it and not sure how to get it up and running.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How do you expect web server to run Ruby script out of itself? Why don;t you use `system` function or similar?

Comment: i tried system, still doesn't work. Like I said, pretty sure it's something to do with ruby

Comment: What did you try? Do you understand what are you doing at all?

Answer (score 2):

First you have install `slim` gem in your sever.

```
gem install slim
```

Next, run the `slimrb` command in php.

```
<?php

$input = "/path/to/foo.slim";
$output = "/path/to/foo.html";

// if this doesn't work, try use the full path of slimrb
exec("slimrb --pretty $input > $output");
```

Comment: I don't think I have access to console on the server? Could I just download the repo from github and put it in the slim folder?

Comment: @user3143218 If your server doesn't have ruby environment, then no way. Just like you don't install php in your server but want to run php code on it.